Matrix will not download in R despite updated version
I was trying to do a linear mixed model in R (lmer) and I got an error Error in initializePtr() :  function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'
I used ChatGPT and it told me to remove Matrix and lme and reinstall it
remove.packages("Matrix")
remove.packages("lme4")
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("lme4")

Unfortunately when I removed Matrix I know can't seem to install it again.
 install.packages("Matrix")
 Warning in install.packages :
   package ‘Matrix’ is not available for this version of R

I updated my R and am now on version Version 2024.04.2+764 but I can't get Matrix to install. I followed all the suggestions on this post but none work.
 tools::package_dependencies("Matrix", which = "LinkingTo", reverse = TRUE)[[1L]]
  [1] "ahMLE"               "bayesWatch"          "cplm"                "GeneralizedWendland"
  [5] "geostatsp"           "hibayes"             "irlba"               "lme4"               
  [9] "mcmcsae"             "OpenMx"              "PRIMME"              "PUlasso"            
  [13] "robustlmm"           "spGARCH"             "TMB"                

I now can't even get the lm to plot on ggplot! Im not sure what to do? Does anyone know what I need to do?

What version is your R? Add output of sessionInfo().

R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.6.6

See https://cran.r-project.org/package=Matrix Depends: "R (≥ 4.4.0)"

It looks like you updated Rstudio, but still running an older version of R.
